# I am confused as to how the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{3+\ln x}{3-\ln x}$ is found.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem within my textbook is $f(x)=$$\frac{3+\ln{x}}{3-\ln{x}}$ I checked the answer and it is $y=$$e^\frac{3x-3}{x+1}$
I've tried many times to simplify the equation after switching the variables but I don't know how to separate the $y$ from the natural logarithm. If someone could show me the steps involved I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you type out what you have tried so far so we can try to spot your error?

Comment: If you have $\ln y = ....something to do with(x)...$ then just raise $e$ to both sides of the equation.  $y = e^{\ln y} = e^{....something to do with (x)....}$.

Comment: ....  but you need to get $\ln y = .... somethingtodo with (x)...$ can you see how $x = \frac {3+\ln y}{3-\ln y}\implies \ln y = \frac {3x -3}{x+1}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, as always you want to solve for $y$ in

$x = \frac {3+\ln y}{3-\ln y}$

$x(3-\ln y) = (3 + \ln y)$

$3x - 3 = \ln y + x\ln y$

$(x+1) \ln y = 3x-3$

$\ln y = \frac {3x-3}{x+1}$

$e^{\ln y} = e^{\frac {3x-3}{x+1}}$

So $y = e^{\frac {3x-3}{x+1}}$

> I don't know how to seperate the y from the natural logarithm

Then inverse of $\ln y = K$ is $e^{\ln y} = y = e^K$.  $\ln x$ and $e^x$ are inverses of each other.  You "cancel" $\ln y=k$ by raising $e$ to the value to get $y = e^k$, and you "cancel" $e^y = M$ by taking the natural log to get $y = \ln M$.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

Start with:$$y=\frac{3+\ln x}{3-\ln x}$$

Rewrite the equality as: $$\ln x=g(y)$$ and conclude that: $$x=e^{\ln x}=e^{g(y)}$$

Now switch $x$ and $y$ to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{3+\ln x}{3-\ln x}$$

Swap $(x,y)$ to find inverse. This is the procedure!

$$x=\frac{3+\ln y}{3-\ln y}$$

Componendo/Dividendo

$$\frac{x-1}{x+1}= \dfrac{2 \ln y}{6}$$

$$ y \rightarrow  y_{\,(inv-fn)} = e^{\frac{3(x-1)}{(x+1)} } $$

Also the graphs reflect each other with respect to mirror line $ y=x.$

The basic rule or definition of log /exp is the same

$$ A = ln_{base}C \rightarrow base^{A}= C. $$